# How to find the length or existence of an array/activerecord relation within an activerecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models:

```
class Listing
  has_many :shipping_selections
end
```

&

```
class ShippingSelection
  belongs_to :listing

  enum status: { incomplete: 0, complete: 1 }
end
```

**I need to write a query that will return me listings that do not have any attached shipping_selections with a 'complete' status.**

I have tried things like this:

```
Listing.includes(:shipping_selections).where('shipping_selections.complete.any? != ?, true)
```

However I got the following error:
"ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid: wrong number of bind variables (1 for 2) in: shipping_selections.complete.any? = ?"

It seems that you cannot use ruby methods like this in the SQL statement.

I then tried to use SQL statments instead, such as this:

```
Listing.where('cardinality(shipping_selections.complete) != ?, 0')
```

However this also didn't seem to work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: To clarify what I want returned, I want ALL listings EXCEPT those which have shipping_selections with a 'complete' status. In the returned list should include listings with no shipping_selections at all.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get an error is because you try to query in SQL. So what happens is that it tries to read your code in pure SQL, and SQL does not include any built in Rails functions. If you want to query in SQL you need to check for `status == 0` and not `.complete`, it does not exist in a SQL context. That is built in active record rails functions which allows us to write it like so. What you are looking for is something like this: `Listing.where(shipping_selections: shipping_selections.inclomplete)`

Comment: Your reasoning is spot on, but I'm not sure the solution provided is what I need.

Comment: Ah, kk saw your clarification now. Try this: `Listing.where.not(ShippingSelection: ShippingSelection.complete)`

Comment: All i get in the console when I run that is: 
```#<Listing::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x2abfb1f44cdc>```
Which suggests an error in the query

Comment: Hmm, interesting how it can handle `where` but not `where.not` in the case of enum, sounds like a bug. Won't bother fixing it as it seems you got the answer from the comment above. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you want to use ruby code as a SQL statement. So, as you are using enum for the `status` field, you can use these:

- To get Listing array with completed shipping selections:

```
    Listing.joins(:shipping_selections).merge(ShippingSelection.complete)
```

- To get Listing array with incompleted shipping selections:

```
    Listing.joins(:shipping_selections).merge(ShippingSelection.incomplete)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Although it didn't exactly give the answer I wanted, I used the first of your suggested queries and subtracted it from the original list to leave me with what I needed. 